# Queues and Webworkers with Laravel

Tags: php, queue, laravel-5, web-worker

Im just getting started with Queues, and they work fine for messaging and sending emails and SMS's to Twilio etc.

But now I want to do something more complex, and time consuming. I'm looking to upload a file of about 10,000 rows to AmazonS3, parse it, check for duplicates, and then only insert records that aren't duplicates.

When I run this process it takes over 6 minutes to complete. Which is way to long. I want to have this run in the background, with a visual progress bar that gets updated sporadically, based on the queue status.

Also, while this is running, I want the users to have full access to the site and database tables. This process, will lock my main table.
So I basically want to have it run in the background, only touch the main table once to check for duplicates, and from there, just proces/parse the file into a temporary table of 10,000+ rows. While leaving the other table free.

Once completed...it will then only write back to the main table once.

How can I achieve this without slowing the site/main server down?? I apologize for the extremely broad question

Answer (score 2):

[Laravel Queues](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues) can do what you want, but there are a couple of points to address in your email.

**How can I achieve this without slowing the site/main server down?**

Well, the queue is run as a separate process on the server, so you *probably* won't see a major impact on the server, provided your background process doesn't do anything too stressful for the server. If you're concerned about an impact on performance and you're running a Linux server, there are options for limiting the resources used by processes - check out the `renice` command which allows you to adjust the priority of processes. If you're not on Linux, then there are probably other options for your OS.

With respect to the database, that's harder to answer without knowing what your tables look like. It might be possible to do the check for duplicates with a single query and `JOIN` on the two tables, perhaps writing the results of the check to a different table. This *might* work, but it could also take a long time depending on how the tables are set up. Another solution would be to use a mirror of the main database table - copy it temporarily, do your work, then delete it. And finally, for a **really** involved solution, set up database replication and work off a slave.

As for running the queue worker, I have found that using `supervisord` to run my background working is VERY helpful - it allows me to start/stop the process easily and will automatically restart the process when it fails. The [documentation on queue listeners](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#running-the-queue-listener) has some discussion of this.

And the worker will fail - I have found that my worker process fails on a pretty regular basis. I think it has something to do with the PHP CLI settings, but it hasn't caused me any issues so I haven't really investigated it further. However, for a long-running job, you might run into difficulties. One way to mitigate this would be to break your job up into multiple smaller jobs and "daisy-chain" them together: when part1 finishes, it queues up part2; when part2 finishes, it queues up part3, etc.

As for the progress bar, that's pretty easy. Have the jobs update a value (in your database probably, or possibly in the filesystem) with the current status and have a Javascript function on the client periodically performing an AJAX request to get that value & update the progress bar.